# How to keep the ?error on url if page extension not included?

Tags: php, .htaccess

I was able to remove the .php or .html extension on my url e.g "localhost/index.php" to "localhost/index" instead. But, on pages with forms, when redirecting back to the form page with the `header('Location: /index.php?error=whatever);` when there are errors, the ?error=whatever is not included. Like, before it would be "localhost/index.php?error=whatever", but now since I removed the page extension, it just returns to "localhost/index". The error message is not showing up. What I have only done to remove the page extension is via the *.htaccess* with this code

```
#turn on url rewriting 
RewriteEngine on

#remove the need for .php extention 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

What do you guys think I should or could do to fix this?

Comment: Take a look at the [QSA](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html#flag_qsa) flag

Comment: What other directives do you have? If you are redirecting to `/index.php?error=whatever` then the code you've posted is not being triggered. However, if you are not using file extensions on your URLs then you shouldn't be redirecting to `index.php` in the first place. (_Aside:_ Simply adding the `QSA` flag to the above rule will do nothing. @brombeer)

Comment: BTW, the code you posted does not "remove the page extension", it "removes the **need** for .php extension" as the code comment suggests.